Run collapsed sections in Jupyter Notebook
In Jupyter Notebook (version 7.0.8), is it possible to run all the cells hidden under a specific section, without expanding it?
See the following example

I have selected the header, which is in in Markdown, but now I want to run all hidden cells. Any efficient way to do this? Perhaps there exists an extension?

" is it possible to run all the cells hidden under a specific section, without expanding it?"  I am assuming you mean to have asked run only collapsed sections? Meaning limit it to just that section? Because otherwise I'm not following what you are sayin because what you are asking is what happens. If I restart a kernel and run all code in notebooks that have hidden sections, the sections get run without expanding in both Jupyter Notebook 7.04 and 7.2.0. So it should be the same in 7.0.8, unless there is an issue. However, I do see in Jupyter Notebook 7.20, when I toggle on showing the ...

 'Table of Contents' from under the 'View' menu, and then right-click on the heading in the Table of Contents and choose 'Select and Run Cells for this Heading' that it does cause the cells to be all uncollapsed and show the input and output for that entire section, in other words the formerly collapsed state is then not maintained & running a Hidden section that way then means it will not be hidden. Yet if you do run all or run any below a point, the section stays in the 'Collapsed view' state.

@Wayne Hi! That is exactly what I mean, yes. Running only the collapsed section. I see, I guess I would like to run only a collapsed section without having to run the entire notebook, nor everything below a point. A bit like what you can do in a Mathematica notebook, for example.

Thanks for pointing out that is a Mathematica-like feature. That prompted me to recall here that covered an idea how to do it. There is this related discussion & here, too, because I wonder if using ...

 ipylab you could get something closer to what you want. Also do you need to be in the notebook to do this? I could think of a way you could do this if you are triggering the notebook to run from the command line or inside another notebook. You can use nbformat to extract all the hidden cells  and place them in a new notebook and run that and then place the result back in the original notebook.
